# Open form with manageable products

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-9

In Bill Of Materials we can make product from other products. as you can see in picture 1 there is Test Product made from 2 other product.

[image]

in Sale Order line I made button that opens this form with Product Price and  Qty

[image]

**But** the goal is to open form where i can manage products that Test Product are build from and change qty and price there.

```
 <record id="view_order_line_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale.order.line.forma</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Sales Order Lines">
                    <field name="product_id" />
                    <field name="product_uom_qty" string="Qty" placeholder="Qty"/>
                    <field name="price_unit" string="Price"/>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record> 


class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.line"

    @api.multi
    def button_details(self):
        context = self.env.context.copy()
        context['view_buttons'] = True
        view_id = self.env.ref('cfg.view_order_line_form_view').id
        view = {
            'name': _('Details'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'sale.order.line',
            'views' : [(view_id,'form')],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'readonly': True,
            'res_id': self.id,
            'context': context
        }
        return view
```

Comment: Why don't you use the form view which is already defined for `sale.order.line`? There are some settings to activate to get this view showed, but you can do it by yourself, if none of this settings can be used. One example setting: Settings / Configuration / Sales -> Warehouse Features -- Product properties on order lines. This setting will "activate" an `sale.order` form view extension which removes the `editable="bottom"` attribute for `order_line`.

Comment: the thing that i will need to change price and qty of products in view that buttons open and after changes are made Test Product price should be recalculated. Because now price of Test Product doesn't depends on price and qty of products that it's made from. For exmpl. i remove 1 qty from product in bom.line and then Test Product price should drop.

Comment: That behaviour could be realised with odoo's pricelists feature, no need for customization.

Comment: Can you please add more details how can i achieve that?

Comment: Activate the feature in sales settings and then look into the pricelists. Maybe there is tutorial in the web, i won't do one here, because i don't have the time for that ;-)

Comment: https://tutorialopenerp.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/odoo-8-pricelist/ this seems good.

Comment: i just checked it doubt it will help me. i should have ability to add and delete products change qty and price , and all this changes should reflect in my sale.order.line product. it's to complicated for end user so he wants to have button and popup where he can change all this fast and easy